# Why is the ossia in Wilde Jagd (Transcendental Etude 8) the same as the regular part?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

[image]

In Wilde Jagd (Transcendental Etude 8) by Liszt, there is an ossia on measure 191.

The ossia and non-ossia parts only differ by where the 8va is placed. But they have the same content --- the notes which don't have a 8va are simply written one octave higher than the corresponding note in the ossia.

What is the purpose of the ossia?

Comment: There is a difference, G instead of Bb and B, in the second and third measures shown. The first of the measures indeed looks identical.

Comment: And if the question is why bother with an identical first measure, perhaps it's just that it's visually easier to start the ossia at the start of the line than to jump to it after a measure.

Answer (score 6):

The two are not identical. The ossia jumps to G where the primary jumps to Bb and B in the second and third measures, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose is almost certainly to avoid requiring the uppermost Bb, since at the time there were still a lot of 85-key pianos that didn't have it.

Comment: You forgot the B natural.